# How to Resume video after SeekTo() method in VideoView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a VideoView and when I pause video, then leave the page and come back - I need to resume video from last position.
But I have a problem - after SeekTo() method video starts from beginning.

I tried to put SeekTo() in SetSource to AutoPlay but nothing is changed((

Here is my VideoPlayerRender:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(VideoPlayer),
                          typeof(FormsVideoLibrary.Droid.VideoPlayerRenderer))]

namespace FormsVideoLibrary.Droid
{
    public class VideoPlayerRenderer : ViewRenderer<VideoPlayer, ARelativeLayout>
    {
        VideoView videoView;
        MediaController mediaController;    // Used to display transport controls
        bool isPrepared;

        public VideoPlayerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<VideoPlayer> args)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(args);

            if (args.NewElement != null)
            {
                if (Control == null)
                {
                    // Save the VideoView for future reference
                    videoView = new VideoView(Context);

                    // Put the VideoView in a RelativeLayout
                    ARelativeLayout relativeLayout = new ARelativeLayout(Context);
                    relativeLayout.AddView(videoView);

                    // Center the VideoView in the RelativeLayout
                    ARelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                        new ARelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
                    layoutParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterInParent);
                    videoView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;

                    // Handle a VideoView event
                    videoView.Prepared += OnVideoViewPrepared;

                    SetNativeControl(relativeLayout);
                }

                SetAreTransportControlsEnabled();
                SetSource();

                args.NewElement.UpdateStatus += OnUpdateStatus;
                args.NewElement.PlayRequested += OnPlayRequested;
                args.NewElement.PauseRequested += OnPauseRequested;
                args.NewElement.StopRequested += OnStopRequested;
            }

            if (args.OldElement != null)
            {
                args.OldElement.UpdateStatus -= OnUpdateStatus;
                args.OldElement.PlayRequested -= OnPlayRequested;
                args.OldElement.PauseRequested -= OnPauseRequested;
                args.OldElement.StopRequested -= OnStopRequested;
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (Control != null && videoView != null)
            {
                videoView.Prepared -= OnVideoViewPrepared;
            }
            if (Element != null)
            {
                Element.UpdateStatus -= OnUpdateStatus;
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        void OnVideoViewPrepared(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            isPrepared = true;
            ((IVideoPlayerController)Element).Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(videoView.Duration);
            var mediaPlayer = sender as MediaPlayer;
            var startTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
            if (App.CurrentPosition > startTime)
            {
                var position = (int)App.CurrentPosition.TotalMilliseconds;
                ****mediaPlayer.SeekTo(position);****
                ((IElementController)Element).SetValueFromRenderer(VideoPlayer.PositionProperty, position);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, args);

            if (args.PropertyName == VideoPlayer.AreTransportControlsEnabledProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                SetAreTransportControlsEnabled();
            }
            else if (args.PropertyName == VideoPlayer.SourceProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                SetSource();
            }
            else if (args.PropertyName == VideoPlayer.PositionProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(videoView.CurrentPosition - Element.Position.TotalMilliseconds) > 1000)
                {
                    videoView.SeekTo((int)Element.Position.TotalMilliseconds);
                }
            }
        }

        void SetAreTransportControlsEnabled()
        {
            if (Element.AreTransportControlsEnabled)
            {
                mediaController = new MediaController(Context);
                mediaController.SetMediaPlayer(videoView);
                videoView.SetMediaController(mediaController);
            }
            else
            {
                videoView.SetMediaController(null);

                if (mediaController != null)
                {
                    mediaController.SetMediaPlayer(null);
                    mediaController = null;
                }
            }
        }

        void SetSource()
        {
            isPrepared = false;
            bool hasSetSource = false;

            if (Element.Source is UriVideoSource)
            {
                string uri = (Element.Source as UriVideoSource).Uri;

                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri))
                {
                    videoView.SetVideoURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(uri));
                    hasSetSource = true;
                }
            }
            else if (Element.Source is FileVideoSource)
            {
                string filename = (Element.Source as FileVideoSource).File;

                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filename))
                {
                    videoView.SetVideoPath(filename);
                    hasSetSource = true;
                }
            }
            else if (Element.Source is ResourceVideoSource)
            {
                string package = Context.PackageName;
                string path = (Element.Source as ResourceVideoSource).Path;

                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path).ToLowerInvariant();
                    string uri = "android.resource://" + package + "/raw/" + filename;
                    videoView.SetVideoURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(uri));
                    hasSetSource = true;
                }
            }

            if (hasSetSource && Element.AutoPlay)
            {
                    videoView.Start();
            }
        }

        // Event handler to update status
        void OnUpdateStatus(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            VideoStatus status = VideoStatus.NotReady;
            var startTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
            if (isPrepared)
            {
                status = videoView.IsPlaying ? VideoStatus.Playing : VideoStatus.Paused;
            }

            TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(videoView.CurrentPosition);
            ((IElementController)Element).SetValueFromRenderer(VideoPlayer.PositionProperty, timeSpan);

            if (status == VideoStatus.Paused &&
                timeSpan > startTime &&
                !isApplicationInTheBackground())
            {
                App.CurrentPosition = timeSpan;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [XamarinMediaManager](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager) and all works.